# Two StoryboardViewController in one iPhone ViewController

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

So what I want is I have two ViewControllers in my Storyboard, one is supposed to be displayed when the current pageControl page is 0, the other one is for page 1.
Let's say I have AViewController and BViewController, both are from the same class TestViewController. I have properties from both classes in my TestViewController.h file, so that works. It loads AViewController but when I try to display BViewController nothing happens. I know I can do this by using multiple View but that can be confusing so two ViewController in my Storyboard does seem like a good solution. What I've tried to display the view is adding it as a subview, i also set the frame programmatically and setHidden = false, i also created another view and sub viewed the table into the view and then this view into the original one but nothing has worked so far. Now I'm wondering is that even possible and how'd I do this?

Comment: What is your problem? Are you saying that you want to switch view controllers programmatically?

Comment: No. I wish I could post a picture. I have an UIPageControl and when the currentPage is 0, I want to display AViewController, when it is 1 I want to display BViewController but I don't want to change the ViewController, only what is displayed. I set everything up in my Storyboard and there I want to have each view in a different ViewController so I can differentiate them